# How to query two tables using ST_Within?

Tags: postgis

I am stuck trying to find out how to see if points from my parking table exists in the polygons in my community districts table. So basically the the community districts table contains a borocd(borough ID) and the_geom(polygon geometry). The parking table has a zipcode column and a thegeom(point geometry). I am trying to figure out how to see if thegeom(from parking) is within the_geom(community district number 101). So basically my community district table looks like:

```
boroid   the_geom
101    | 0106000020D7080000040000000103000000010000003803000000728A4...
102    | 0106332020D7080000040000000103000000010000003093000000998A4...
101    | 0107112020D7080000040000000103000000010000003803000000087A4...
```

And my parking table looks like:

```
 zipcode |                      thegeom                       
---------+----------------------------------------------------
  11203 | 0101000020E6100000000000C0C351444000000000817C52C0
  14634 | 0101000020E6100000000000C0D0564440000000A0597152C0
  13401 | 0101000020E6100000000000804D584440000000C0B37E52C0
```

The query I am trying to run is:

```
select a.thegeom from parking a, cd b  where b.boroid = '101' AND  ST_WITHIN(a.thegeom,b.the_geom);
```

After I run this query nothing is displayed.

Comment: Show your geometries as WKT `select ST_AsText(the_geom)...`.

Comment: Have you mixed borocd and boroid?

Comment: I shall update my question since the query yields too much numbers to fit into this text box.

Comment: I meant boroid will update

Comment: @user30184 I'm sorry mate, the WKT conversion is too much to fit into the textbox. I narrow it down to this:  MULTIPOLYGON(((983328.653400004 196356.027899995,983256.688299999 196295.017499998,983243.033500001 196283.606800005,983249.644400001 196275.581900
001,983263.1417 196286.713699996,983451.924199998 196065.565899998,983425.851400003 196041.934, 9
72948.434699997 193867.2632………)))

Comment: Right now I can only tell that this returns true `select ST_Within
(ST_GeomFromText('POINT ( 184 168 )'),ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON ((( 98 185, 265 205, 204 114, 134 128, 98 185 )))'))`. Simplify your query as much as possible, test that you get an answer with one known point and multipolygon and add more elements to the query after that.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 problems like this are because the geometries are in different projections.  In your case it appears no different.  The first point in your parking table has a value of `POINT(40.638786315918 -73.9453735351563)`.  This would appear to be WGS84 or something similar while your districts appear to be projected

Comment: I flagged to close because none of this information is pertinent or relevant. It has nothing to do with ST_Within or a query. Instead the user was just confusing long,lat, with lat,long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projections from both tables need to be the same. Either both in [EPSG:2236](http://epsg.io/2263) (I'm guessing here), or both in [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326), but not mixed. Here is a query, rewritten to be tidier using a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.thegeom
FROM parking a
JOIN cd b ON b.boroid='101' AND
             ST_Within(ST_Transform(a.thegeom, 4326), ST_Transform(b.the_geom, 4326));
```

---

Or another common reason is to make sure geometries are using a common axis order, i.e. (X Y) or (lon lat) and *never* (Y X) or (lat lon). On closer inspection it seems the points have flipped coordinates.

The hex-encoded WKB point `0101000020E6100000000000C0C351444000000000817C52C0` has EWKT `SRID=4326;POINT(40.638786315918 -73.9453735351563)`, or human-readable (via [ST_AsLatLonText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html)) as 73°56'43.345"S 40°38'19.631"E, which is a point on Antarctica.

The axis order can be corrected with [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html), i.e.:

```
UPDATE parking SET thegeom = ST_FlipCoordinates(thegeom);
```

And you should see coordinates like 40°38'19.631"N 73°56'43.345"W in New York. Spatial search queries should start working as expected now.

Comment: hey mate, thanks for your response but unfortunately your query outputs a blank column as a.thgeom

Comment: @ThomasC it's difficult to do anything without specific examples of your geometries. It would be best for you to print out two geometries that you expect to intersect with either hex-encoded EWKB (default) or using ST_AsEWKT. Even just a snippet would help.

Comment: Hey mate, So this is a point in the parking table:"0101000020D70800004D436ECB5CC9A041FE5B64F7A28E68C1" and here is a polygon in the borotable:"0106000020E61000000300000001030000000100000071000000EA229090667C52C01A3B33BD33644440D85F3C07637C52C01567FC6D3564444097848FBB647C52C0BD86E4132E644440AE9E838A687C52C0B6DE1A3E096444401C80E560687C52C093D851C100644440BE763DF3637C52C098440641DC634440F454AB9D5D7C (...)" note they both are EPSG:4326

Comment: It's difficult to see much with an incomplete EWKB, but I can with an incomplete EWKT. What I'm looking for is the SRID and the magnitude of coordinate values from the first few coordinates.

Comment: hey mate thanks for your patience, so here is the EWKT the point is: "SRID=4326;POINT(40.761360168457 -73.9577789306641)" and the polygon is: "SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((-73.9437600524504 40.7828289508963,-73.9435442056268 40.7828805429873,-73.9436482335608 40.7826561799861,-73.9438806805944 40.7815320616914,-73.9438707581725 40.7812730455054,-73.9436004734261 40.7801591187101,-73.9432138608134 40. (...)" I am unable to get all the data for the polygon.

Comment: @ThomasC I found the issue: your point coordinates need to be flipped, as you were searching these on Antarctica. See updated answer.

Comment: Hey mate, cheers. You're answer was suffice.